# Compare element in Dictionary, Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary

During the generation of my elements I also generate a Dictionary with [key,value]

key is an Int

Value is a string.

I gave an example: [1 : A, 2 : B, 3 : A, 4 : B]

So now I know that first and third elements are a pairs!

I also have a function that rotates my element when tapped. When I tap a card I have access to his ID.

What I need is to compare if the tapped card has the same dictionary value of the second tapped card (and if yes don't rotate anymore this card) else rotate down both card.

This is the function I am talking about:

```
    @IBAction func actionPerformed(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if element.transform.rotation.angle == .pi {
            self.firstRotation(element: element)

                } else {
                    self.secondRotation(element: element)

                }

}
```

So lets wrap up, I already have a dictionary with solutions, what I need is to check if the first tapped card is equal to the second, if yes do something, else do other thing.

Comment: Try to save the ID of the first tapped card to a variable, for example firstId, and then compare dictionary[firstId] and dictionary[card.id]

Comment: I have lot of ideas to, could you give me some code? Thanks for answers btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to save the ID of the card to a variable (`firstId`). If this variable is `nil`, it means that this is the first tapped card, else it is the second one.

```
var firstId: Int?

@IBAction func onTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapLocation = sender.location(in: arView)
    if let card = arView.entity(at: tapLocation) {
        if let firstId = firstId {
            // second card tapped
            if self.cardEntityCorrelation[firstId] == self.cardEntityCorrelation[card.id] {
                // cards form a pair; no rotation is needed
                // reset firstId to allow selecting the next pair
                self.firstId = nil
            } else {
                // cards do not form a pair
                // rotate second card
                rotate(card: card)
            }
        } else {
            // first card tapped; save id
            firstId = card.id
            // rotate first card
            rotate(card: card)
        }
    }
}

//ROTATE UP OR DOWN
private func rotate(card: Entity) {
    if card.transform.rotation.angle == .pi {
        firstRotation(card: card)
    } else {
        secondRotation(card: card)
    }
}

//ROTATE UP
private func firstRotation(card: Entity) {
    var flipDownTransform = card.transform
    flipDownTransform.rotation = simd_quatf(angle: 0, axis: [1,0,0])
    card.move(to: flipDownTransform, relativeTo: card.parent, duration: 0.25, timingFunction: .easeInOut)
}

//ROTATE DOWN
private func secondRotation(card: Entity) {
    var flipUpTransform = card.transform
    flipUpTransform.rotation = simd_quatf(angle: .pi, axis: [1,0,0])
    card.move(to: flipUpTransform, relativeTo: card.parent, duration: 0.25, timingFunction: .easeInOut)
}
```

Comment: Your answer is really god! Could I ask one more advice (you can save my life right now)

Lets say I have a function that rotates my card topDown and one that rotates downTop.

So if card is down I call the function to rotate it up, else if card is up I call the function to rotate it down

Now that I found my pair, how do I tell ok, first couple, dont rotate anymore, moves on with next card

Comment: You could put rotation function to the necessary places in the code, see comments in my updated code

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but I have some strange behaviour like I can rotate the seconda card if and only if it's equal to the first one
If it is not I'm not able to rotate it 

I update my question could you take a look please, it ' s useless otherwise

THANKS AGAIN

Comment: You rotate the card twice. Remove `self.firstRotation(card: card)` before this line: `if let firstId = firstId {`

Comment: I still have some strange behaviour ...

Are the rotations in the right place and the corrects ones? Do I need the rotation fours lines before the comment // ROTATION UP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214028/discussion-between-atarasenko-and-conteolaf).